# How to have an element not affect the width of a table

Tags: html, html-table, datatables

I have a table with the first column having a title and a subtitle:

[image]

But when the subtitle is too long, the other columns get pushed to the right:

[image]

I understand that this is standard behavior, but is there a way to trick the Browser into ignoring the `<p>` tag when calculating column widths, and then let the subtitle wrap inside the available space? :

Something like this:

[image]

A pen for your perusal: [xxqRrNw](https://codepen.io/shahimclt/pen/xxqRrNw)

PS: I actually intent to use this inside a [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) table. But I've kept it simple for now. I assume what works here will also work in that plugin.

Comment: _"I assume what works here will also work in that plugin."_ - Maybe, yes. But DataTables also has specific support for [column widths](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width). That may be all you need.

Comment: There are also various [questions and answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+column+width+site%3Astackoverflow.com) already on Stack Overflow on this topic. Those can help with more specific issues you may face.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `class="table"` to your table and `table-layout: fixed;` under the `table {...}` in the css.